# Reading Resources needed for Transaction Management in .Net

Tags: .net, architecture, transactions, distributed-transactions, transactionmanager

I need to look into some .Net based Transaction Management for an in-flight project.  Does anyone have any online reading resources that would give me some grounding / background reference when I start looking at what the systems currently doing?

The transactions we talking about are a mix of inter-system / WCF and DB calls.

Comment: Can you explain more, you are looking best practices on how to manage database transactions(transaction scoping) using wcf?

Comment: Not looking for database transaction management specifically.  I want to understand the basic principles behind good transaction management.  .Net specifics - say around around best practice - would be a nice bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout:

- [WCF Transaction Propagation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163432.aspx)
- [Enabling Transaction Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733116.aspx)